# when MP4Box merge videos, cannot play part2 sub video

Tags: linux, shell, video, avconv, mp4box

I wanna add sns accounts in video end, so I have two videos, "/tmp/video/0-1-1-to.mp4" is original video, "/tmp/video/0-1-2-to.mp4" is white board with black text(my accounts), I use:

```
MP4Box -cat /tmp/video/0-1-1-to.mp4 -cat /tmp/video/0-1-2-to.mp4 /tmp/video/0-1.mp4
```

but when i play video with `google-chrome /tmp/video/0-1.mp4` the "/tmp/video/0-1-2-to.mp4 " content cannot be played

[here](https://gist.github.com/roroco/676e7f69cf06f2444c2a411d20dd1542) is two part videos' info, i get them with `avprobe -show_streams path/to/video`

How to format 0-1-2.mp4 to make MP4Box success, 0-1-1.mp4 is big file, I don't wanna format it.

Answer (score 0):

when I `MP4Box -cat /tmp/video/0-1-1-to.mp4 -cat /tmp/video/0-1-2-to.mp4 /tmp/video/0-1.mp4`, it show detail reason, the reason is part1 video profile is diff with part2 profile, i can see the diff with `MP4Box -info path/to/video`

the solution is use `avconv` to convert part2 to make its profile is same with part1